# How to set auth token in http header in angular js resource get

Tags: angularjs, oauth, http-headers

I am trying to access rest api which needed a **Oauth 1.0a** authentication. Currently I have api key, access token. 
How to set Authorization with access token to access api in following code snippet.

1. How syntax looks like for Authorization with access token
2. what are necessary attributes needs to be set
3. Is there any region issues can exist for api access?
4. when it shows **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**. Error

I am trying to set http header in following code snippet,

```
$resource('url', {}, {
                "getData": {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                //? 
                            }
                }
            });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your access token is called `Token`. Your header should looks like this:

```
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Token QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2Ff(Key example)'}
}
```