# Set Token in header in $resource - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and trying to make an  API call with access-token. Below is the service that i am using for this API call.

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app')
        .factory('Student',Student);
        Student.$inject = ['$resource','$rootScope'];
        function Student($resource, $rootScope){ 
            var URL = 'myUrl';
            var details = $resource(URL + ':id/',{
                id:'@id',
            },{ }
        ); 
        return {
            details: details,
        };
    }
})();
```

Inside the controller

```
Student.details.get(function(data){

        console.log(data);

    });
```

My question is, how should i add an access-token with the header of this request? I am having the token in $rootScope. Descriptions shown  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912506/how-to-set-auth-token-in-http-header-in-angular-js-resource-get) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244809/angular-js-set-token-on-header-default) doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a header to your resource you can do something like this:

```
var details = $resource('test', {
    id: '@id',
}, {
    get: {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'dfgasdfjhkjhk3452i34hpiuhasd9f435kjkad'
        }
    }
});
```